# explicit conversion operator and const-reference qualification

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, language-lawyer

The following example compiles fine on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1b77sv) with `-std=c++17` with clang, but fails with msvc and gcc:

```
struct Foo
{
};

struct Bar
{
    explicit operator Foo() // w/o explicit qualification all are happy
    {
        return Foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    const Foo& foo = static_cast<const Foo&>(b); // only clang happy with this
    const Foo& foo2 = static_cast<const Foo&>(static_cast<Foo>(b)); // clang / msvc / gcc happy with this
    return 0;
}
```

So as far as I understand the `explicit` on the operator simply prohibit [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), and since the page lists qualification conversions among them, I would assume clang is simply wrong in this case? Or am I missing something?

I'd ideally want to stick with the single cast, since I am using this in a templated code, where if the const-reference conversion operator is available it is used. But I could also drop the `explicit` constraint.

Comment: I believe `foo` (if it would compile) and `foo2` are dangling references.

Comment: you should do `const Foo& foo2 = static_cast<Foo>(b);` since this will extend the temporary lifetime to the lifetime of the reference, avoiding the dangling reference I mentioned. Also this is just 1 cast without any modifications to your class.

Comment: @bolov The cast expressions could be used in some other context where lifetime is valid,  this is surely just a MRE to house the question about validity of the cast

Comment: @M.M yep :) The example is for the sole purpose to understand if clang is right or not.

Comment: @bolov i did really not pay attention since i wanted to emphasize the 2 casts vs the single cast, but woudn't the const& qualification extend the lifetime here, and these would not be dangling references ?

Comment: Hmm, all three compilers are happy with `const Foo& foo = b;` or `const Foo& foo = static_cast<const Foo&>(b);` if one removes `explicit`. I don't see why adding `explicit` would make the explicit cast illegal suddenly.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis a reference extends only the lifetime of a prvalue. `static_cast<const T&>` is an lvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's example is not really minimal. A truly minimal example uses, instead of a `static_cast` and then an initialization, simply:

```
const Foo& foo(b);
```

This is what `static_cast<const Foo&>(b)` is supposed to do, anyway.

Here again, Clang accepts and GCC rejects [[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1bhfK3)]. If this is changed to a copy-initialization (`const Foo& foo = b;`) then Clang and GCC both reject.

It seems that Clang is correct: in the direct-initialization case, why shouldn't the `explicit` conversion function be used?

The question is tagged c++11, so see C++11 [over.match.ref]/1:

> Under the conditions specified in 8.5.3, a reference can be bound directly to a glvalue or class prvalue that is the result of applying a conversion function to an initializer expression. Overload resolution is used to select the conversion function to be invoked. Assuming that “*cv1* `T`” is the underlying type of the reference being initialized, and “*cv* `S`” is the type of the initializer expression, with `S` a class type, the candidate functions are selected as follows:
>
> - The conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are considered, except that for copy-initialization, only the non-explicit conversion functions are considered. Those that are not hidden within `S` and yield type “lvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`” (when 8.5.3 requires an lvalue result) or “*cv2* `T2`” or “rvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`” (when 8.5.3 requires an rvalue result), where “*cv1* `T`” is reference-compatible (8.5.3) with “*cv2* `T2`”, are candidate functions.

The wording in 8.5.3 was the subject of a [defect report](https://wg21.link/CWG1287) which was resolved in C++14 to clarify that the reference binding does not use an "implicit conversion", but instead a "conversion" (where [over.match.ref] excludes the `explicit` functions only in the copy-initialization case). This resolution should be considered retroactive to C++11.

The wording changes in each edition of the standard but I think the conclusion is the same.

I looked for an existing GCC bug report on this issue, but surprisingly couldn't find one. I think it would be a good idea to open a bug report and, if the GCC devs insist that GCC is correct, they will explain why they think so.